# Java Sorting Arrays (strings, doubles and variables)

Tags: java

I have to create **class SorterDemo** with following mechanisms.

**sortDouble** - `sort array of double variables.`

**sortString** - `sort given String value in alphabetical manner.`

**sortStudent** - `sort array of Student objects based on marks.`

I have create array of double variables, declared one String variable and also array of Student objects in main method. I need to display the output of each array as resulted out of the three sort methods in main method.
I'm getting the following errors:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The field Student.rollNo is not visible
    The field Student.name is not visible
    The field Student.marks is not visible
    The method nextdouble() is undefined for the type Scanner
    The method nextdouble() is undefined for the type Scanner
    Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sortDouble(double[]) from the type SorterDemo`

Also need help in sorting students marks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Student` class `rollNo` is private variable, so you cannot directly access it like this: `stud[i].rollNo`. Instead create a setter for this in your `Student` class like this:

```
public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
  this.rollNo = rollNo;
}
```

And change above code to like this: `stud[i].setRollNo(s.nextInt());`. Do same for `name` and `marks`.

This would work. Also `s.nextdouble();` should be `s.nextDouble();`

Comment: I tried the above edit. I have updated the source code. Please check. Getting Null Pointer Exception Error after inputting 
Also it's showing error in the following line: 


    `String str=String.valueof(arr);`

    `RollNo.Array.sort(arr);`

Answer (score -1):

change  `nextdouble()` to `nextDouble()` and declare `rollNo`,`name`,`marks` as

**Example :**

```
public int rollNo 
public String name;
public double marks;
```

Comment: It is mandatory for me to keep them in private as per the question. Is there any alternative approach?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<stud.length;i++){
     
     int rollno;
     String name;
     double mk;
       System.out.println("enter rollNo: ");
       rollno=sc1.nextInt();
       System.out.println("enter name: ");
       name= sc2.nextLine();
       System.out.println("enter marks: ");
       mk=  sc3.nextDouble();
     stud[i]=new Student(rollno,name,mk);
      
        stud[i].getRollNo(rollno);
      
        stud[i].getName(name);
       
        stud[i].setMarks(mk);
        doub[i]=sc4.nextDouble();
        }

Comment: here Student class object creation is inside the for loop eg: stud[i]=new Student(rollno,name,mk);

Comment: I removed the parameters inside getName() and getRollNo as was showing error. 

Hence    `for(int i=0;i<stud.length;i++) { 
         int rollno; 
         String name;
         double marks;
         System.out.println("enter rollNo: ");
         rollno=sc1.nextInt();
         System.out.println("enter name: ");
         name= sc2.nextLine();
         System.out.println("enter marks: ");
   marks = sc3.nextDouble(); 
   stud[i]=new Student(rollno,name,marks); 
   stud[i].getRollNo(); 
   stud[i].getName(); 
   stud[i].setMarks(marks);
   doub[i]=sc4.nextDouble(); 
         } `

Comment: After inputting Marks, it goes into endless loop. Can you please help me for sorting the students marks as well?

Comment: Try this ,for(int i=0;i<stud.length;i++){int rollno;String name;double mk;System.out.println("enter rollNo: "); rollno=sc1.nextInt();
 System.out.println("enter name: "); name= sc2.nextLine();
System.out.println("enter marks: ");mk=  sc3.nextDouble();
stud[i]=new Student(rollno,name,mk);doub[i]=  stud[i].getMarks();
}System.out.println("array before sorting double variables: ");
 for(int i=0;i<stud.length;i++){System.out.println(doub[i]);
}  System.out.println("array after sorting double variables: "); doub=sortDouble(doub);for(int i=0;i<stud.length;i++){ System.out.println(doub[i]);}

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Next problem I'm facing is in ***sortString()** for sorting the strings(Student names in this case) alphabetically. It says that `The method sort(char[]) is undefined for the type Array`. How is this possible when assign is correct? Lastly, I have to print the student names according to marks.

Comment: I canot use java.util.Arrays package so, Am i give any another sorting method?

Comment: declare  String[] studentArray=new String[5]; same as doub  and inside for loop studentArray[i]=stud[i].getName(); and out of for loop call  studentArray=sortString(studentArray);  public static String[] sortString(String[] names){ String temp; for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
          {
              for (int j = i + 1; j <names.length; j++) 
              {if (names[i].compareTo(names[j])>0) 
                  { temp = names[i];
                      names[i] = names[j];
                      names[j] = temp;}  }} return names; }

Comment: `Same as doub and for loop` as in I have to declare it again for user input? Can't we use the variables declared before as input and then sort

Comment: Completely edit the main source code if you can. Thanks.

Comment: i can't write complete code here so i split each section.first declaration Student stud[]=new Student[5];
    double[] doub=new double[5];
    double[] FinalMarkArray=new double[5];
    String[] studentArray=new String[5];
    String[] studentArray1=new String[5];
    Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc3=new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: first for loop in main method ,   for(int i=0;i<stud.length;i++){int rollno;
String name;double mk; System.out.println("enter rollNo: ");
 rollno=sc1.nextInt(); System.out.println("enter name: ");
 name= sc2.nextLine();System.out.println("enter marks: "); mk=  sc3.nextDouble();
      stud[i]=new Student(rollno,name,mk);       
      studentArray[i]=stud[i].getName();        
         doub[i]=  stud[i].getMarks(); }

Comment: out of first for lopp  for(int j=0;j<doub.length;j++){
     FinalMarkArray[j]=doub[j];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<studentArray.length;j++){
     studentArray1[j]=studentArray[j];
    }

Comment: then  FinalMarkArray=sortDouble(FinalMarkArray);     
    studentArray1=sortString(studentArray1);

Comment: then   System.out.println("Marks in Ascending Order: ");
    for(int i=0;i<FinalMarkArray.length;i++){
     
     for(int j=0;j<doub.length;j++){
      
       if(FinalMarkArray[i]==doub[j]){
        
         System.out.println("Name :"+studentArray[j] + " Mark= "+FinalMarkArray[i]);
       }
        
     }
     
    }

Comment: then System.out.println("Name in Ascending Order: ");
    for(int i=0;i<studentArray1.length;i++){
     
     for(int j=0;j<studentArray.length;j++){
      
       if(studentArray1[i].equals(studentArray[j])){
        
         System.out.println("Name :"+studentArray1[i] + " Mark= "+doub[j]);
       }
        
     }
     
    }

Comment: public static double[] sortDouble(double[] marks){
 
  
  double temp;
    for (int i = 0; i <marks.length; i++) 
         {
             for (int j = i + 1; j < marks.length; j++) 
             {
                 if (marks[i] >marks[j]) 
                 {
                     temp =marks[i];
                     marks[i] =marks[j];
                     marks[j] = temp;
                 }
             }
         }
   return marks;
    }

Comment: public static String[] sortString(String[] names){
   
    String temp;
   
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) 
          {
              for (int j = i + 1; j <names.length; j++) 
              {
                  if (names[i].compareTo(names[j])>0) 
                  {
                      temp = names[i];
                      names[i] = names[j];
                      names[j] = temp;
                   
                  }
              }
          }
    
    return names;
     
      }